# How to populate variable using execution function in tsql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, exec, execution

EDITED:

I am running the following query

```
DECLARE @value0 INT; 
DECLARE @filter = 'values.country = ''Germany''';
EXEC('SELECT 
'+@value0+' = SUM(CASE WHEN valuecolumn >= 0   
AND valuecolumn < 31  THEN POWER(2, valuecolumn - 0) ELSE 0 END) ,
'+@value1+' = SUM(CASE WHEN valuecolumn >= 32  AND valuecolumn < 63  THEN 
POWER(2, valuecolumn - 32)  ELSE 0 END)
FROM dbo.values
where '+@filter+'');
```

when I am executing this query I am getting this error :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near '='.

The filter is a dynamic variable that I need to use and that is why I am using execution function.
How is it possible to fill a declared variable using execution function?

Comment: Have a look at [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Comment: Why do you use dynamic SQL for this in the first place?

Comment: @Zohar Peled 
I edited my question as an answer to your question

Comment: And I've edited my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do need to execute dynamic sql with an output parameter, you must use `sp_executesql`:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1500),
        @ParmDefinition NVARCHAR(500),
        @value0 INT,
        @filter NVARCHAR(1000);

-- Set the @filter values here....

SET @sql = 'SELECT @result = SUM(
                   CASE WHEN valuecolumn >= 0 AND valuecolumn < 31 THEN 
                       POWER(2, valuecolumn - 0)
                   ELSE 
                       0 
                   END) FROM dbo.values
             WHERE '+ @filter

SET @ParmDefinition = N'@result int OUTPUT';

EXEC sp_executesql @Sql, @ParmDefinition, @result = @value0 OUTPUT;
```

Please note that this use of your `@Filter` parameter is **vulnerable to SQL injection attacks.** If possible, you should refactor this query into something safe (using catch-all techniques).

Comment: Must declare the scalar variable "@result".

Comment: and when I am declaring : Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'SELECT ' to data type int. I am not quite sure how does this work

Comment: Sorry, I've misplaced the `@result` and `@value0` in the `exec` statement. Edited my answer.

Comment: and if I have value0 = sum(), value1 = sum(), value2 = sum(), value3 = sum().. etc I have to make for each of them different ParmDefinition?

Comment: No, you concatenate them: `SET @ParmDefinition = N'@value0 int output, @value1 int output, @value3 int output'...`